# Add Team options for SVN repository access to custom context menu?

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu, eclipse-kepler

Is it possible to add the Team options for SVN repository access to a custom context menu on a custom view? If so, how?

I have tried

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:my.view.ID#PopupMenu">
    <menu id="team.main" label="Team">
        <separator name="group1" visible="false"/>
        <separator name="group2" visible="false"/>
        <separator name="group3" visible="false"/>
    </menu>
```

in my plugin.xml, but only an EGit menu popped up once with grayed items when the mouse hovered over them.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `org.eclipse.team.svn.ui` plugin to see how the actions are defined. This uses the old style `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point with `objectContribution` entries. For most entries on single files the object contribution is defined as:

```xml
<objectContribution
        adaptable="true"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping"
        id="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.ResourceContributions">

     <enablement>
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping">
          <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectPersistentProperty" args="org.eclipse.team.core.repository,org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature" />
       </adapt>
     </enablement>
```

Which means the actions will only show for objects which adapt to `ResourceMapping` and are in a project with the SVN nature and a repository. `IFile` objects normally adapt to `ResourceMapping` but if you are using some other object you will have to set this up yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. If I implement IProject / IFile for the objects in my custom view and provide the menu groups group.new / group.open / ... / svn.main for the popup menu it works.

Comment: Another important thing are the adapters for the view's content objects. E.g. for the team menu the adapter org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping needs to be checked in getAdapter().